# How to display both svg and png images from database?

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc

So I have some images stored in the database. They consist of both png and svg images. But I cannot display the svg images but the png images are displayed correctly.

```
public ActionResult GetImage() {
    // some code here
    return new FileContentResult(image, "image/png");
}
```

How can I display both **svg** and **png**?

Comment: use `image/svg+xml` mime-type instead of `image/png` for svg images?

Comment: @JonasH but i also have png images.

Comment: are you retrieving the images as urls or base64 encoded?

Comment: @ShaiCohen As url

Comment: so, return different mime-types depending on the actual file-type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The svg images was not displayed because of the wrong content type in FileContentResult.

So the solution is to find the content type:

```
public ActionResult GetImage() {
    // some code here
    var contentType = GetContentType(image);
    return new FileContentResult(image, contentType);
}

private string GetContentType(byte[] image)
{
    var returnType = "image/png";
    var fileheader = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(image, 0, 25);
    if (fileheader.StartsWith("<?xml ") || fileheader.StartsWith("<svg ") || fileheader.StartsWith("\r\n<svg "))
        returnType = "image/svg+xml";
    return returnType;
}
```